# What's the difference between 2 JavaScript objects?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

I try do improve my JavaScript skills.
I don't understand why (5) works and (2) returns error. Isn't the same?

1. B.fn()          //OK
2. B.fn2()         //TypeError: Object # has no method 'fn2'
3. var a = new A()
4. a.fn()          //OK
5. a.fn2()         //OK

   ```
   var A = function () {
       this.fn = function () { alert(3); }
   }
   A.prototype = {
       fn2: function () { alert(4); }
   };

   var B =
       {
           fn: function () { alert(1); }
       }
   B.prototype = {
       fn2: function () { alert(2); }
   };
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(easy explanation)
The `prototype` property only applies when using a `function` as constructor (by using the `new` operator). The `function` creates a clone of it's `prototype` and the `this` keyword inside the function is set to the clone. The properties on the clone are direct references/pointers to the `prototypes` properties.

The object literal `{}` is a more powerfull expression alternative to `new Object()` and as such "inherits" properties from `Object.prototype`.

So:

```
function ClassLike() {}
ClassLike.prototype = {
    foo : "bar"
}

var instance = new ClassLike();
alert( instance.foo ); // bar
```

Works because the `new` operator kicks some operations in motion to create a new object whereas:

```
var instance = {
    foo : "bar"
}
instance.prototype = {
    baz : "foobar"
}
```

Merely adds another property (prototype) to an already created object and no process is put in motion to actually assign/change the objects original prototype.

Now Mozilla has added a non standard (IE does not support it) way to change an already instantiated objects prototype through `__proto__` and there are some petitions going to add it to ES5 (EcmaScript 5). I would not use it atm. but it works like this:

```
var instance = {};
var parent = {
    foo : "bar"
}
instance.__proto__ = parent;

alert( instance.foo ); // bar
```

Another way to change an already instantiated object's prototype is to add to the `Object` constructors prototype (which is not advised for many reasons). As such:

```
var instance = {}; // a more powerful alternative to `new Object()`

Object.prototype.foo = "bar";

alert( instance.foo ); // bar
```

It's all possible, though wether it's wise to do it... I'd say no, but opinions vary and I rather avoid the debate ;)

Anyways, just remember that the `prototype` property on works when you `new` a `function`, otherwise it just becomes a property on the instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have relative question. I need privileged functions for accessing private members, right? If yes, so why when I call "new C().fn()", "this" doesn't see "m" member"? var C = function(){var m; this.fn=function(){return this.m;}}

Comment: `var m` creates a local variable, not a property. `this.m` tries to refer to a public property. The `this` keyword does not work the same as in other languages, it's just an 'injected' variable pointing to the owning object of the function. This would work: `var C = function(){var m=1; this.fn=function(){return m;}}`

Comment: `__proto__` won't be added to ES5: ES5 is already a final non-changing standard. There is, however, `Object.getPrototypeOf(o)` which gives the prototype of `o`. Equally, it's not true to say "now Mozilla have added"; it has existed for a very long time, and also exists in Carakan (Opera), JSC (Safari), and V8 (Chrome).

Answer (score 7):

`a` is an instance of the `A` class, where as `B` is the class itself. Since `fn2` is not defined as static function, it will only be available to an instance of class `B` as opposed to the class `B` itself.

If you wanted to use `B` directly, you could use:

`new B().fn2()`

if you define `B` as a `function()`

Alternatively, you could define `fn2` the same way you have defined `fn`

Comment: Actually `new B().fn2()` wouldn't work because there is no `B()` function defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

What you have demonstrated is caused by something that I would consider the biggest problem with OO in JavaScript: prototype must be a property of the constructor function and not the object itself. It means that if you have a single object that can be easily defined as an object literal, you still need to have a useless constructor just to define the prototype of your object.

Read this article: [Prototypal Inheritance in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) by Douglas Crockford. Here is the relevant part:

> [...] JavaScript itself is conflicted
>   about its prototypal nature. In a
>   prototypal system, objects inherit
>   from objects. JavaScript, however,
>   lacks an operator that performs that
>   operation. Instead it has a `new`
>   operator, such that `new f()` produces
>   a new object that inherits from
>   `f.prototype` This indirection was
>   intended to make the language seem
>   more familiar to classically trained
>   programmers, but failed to do that, as
>   we can see from the very low opinion
>   Java programmers have of JavaScript.
>   JavaScript's constructor pattern did
>   not appeal to the classical crowd. It
>   also obscured JavaScript's true
>   prototypal nature. As a result, there
>   are very few programmers who know how
>   to use the language effectively.
>   Fortunately, it is easy to create an
>   operator that implements true
>   prototypal inheritance. It is a
>   standard feature in my toolkit, and I
>   highly recommend it for yours.

Read the article for some ideas no how to effectively solve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your answer is pretty simple.In JavaScript, only constructors have "prototypes" i.e. the prototype property. Object literals e.g "{}" don't. Therefore, your number 2 will never work unless you change it as follows:

```
var B = function(){ // the B constructor
          return this;
        }
B.prototype = {
fn2: function(){ alert(2); }
}
```